# How to properly copy data from one sheet to another after first empty cell with vba in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button on my sheet that when clicked is supposed to copy data from my "template" sheet below the first blank cell. Unfortunately it instead creates a whole new workbook with the copied data. I have it set to copy the template data when a new sheet is created that works as expected but for some reason this button does not. Here is my code:

```
Sub paste_newcalc()
    Set WshSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")

    Dim rFirstBlank As Range

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    WshSrc.Copy

    Set rFirstBlank = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    With ActiveSheet.Cells
        .PasteSpecial

    End With

End Sub
```

What I have used there is what I have found through searching the internet for a solution.

Comment: Maybe `WshSrc.cells(1, 1).currentregion.Copy` will get you started.

Comment: `WshSrc.Copy`  is the line that copies a worksheet/workbook.  As @Jeeped you want to copy a *range* of that worksheet (even if it's all the cells, with `WshSrc.Cells.Copy` (but I recommend against copying all the cells as the data size could make things slow down).

Comment: Yeah, just found that out. The cell range that needs to be copied is A1:D40

Comment: Great!  Now, make an attempt at copy/pasting that range and let us know how it goes and if you get any errors, etc.

Comment: Ok. Replaced .cells(1,1) with .cells(A1,D40), clicked the button and got a 400 error

Answer (score 1):

Ok. With the help of the comments above, I altered my vba code and found a solution. If I have a default range of data on one sheet, let's call it "Template", and I want to copy that below the data I already have in my current sheet with the click of a button, the following code will do it.

```
Sub paste_newcalc()
    Dim rFirstBlank As Range

    Set rFirstBlank = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    Worksheets("Template").Range("A4:D40").Copy

    rFirstBlank.PasteSpecial


End Sub
```

That will paste the range you want from another sheet below the data you already have in the first empty cell. Thank you to those that commented!

Comment: your sub can collapse to `Worksheets("Template").Range("A4:D40").Copy Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`. because 1) you're not actually using a `PasteSpecial ` feature 2) `ActiveSheet` is the _default_ sheet qualification

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub paste_newcalc()
     Dim rFirstBlank As Range
     Set rFirstBlank = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
     Worksheets("Template").Range("A4:D40").Copy rFirstBlank
End Sub
```